# jQuery filter through content using Regular Expressions with multiple filters?

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I've got a page where I post blocks of content (pretty much like comments on [this page](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_live_comment_search.htm)) and each block consists of Month and Year (date) and Comment. So it looks something like this:

> **August 2016** Comment / text goes here.

And as per the [instructions here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/comment-page-1) I've incorporated that same filtering script on my end to quickly search through the content on that page.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val();

    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".articles li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

However, now I've added two select dropdown elements for Month and Year, where I've just changed the #filter reference to #month,#year (to search through those two elements whose IDs are those, respectively), so I have something like this:

```
<select id="year" name="year">
<option value="">Year</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
...
</select>
```

and same for Month:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
...
</select>
```

and the jQuery search/filter for those two looks like this:

```
$("#year,#month").change(function(){
        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter_year = $("#year").val();
        var filter_month = $('#month').val();
        var filter_date = $('#month').val() + ' ' + $('#year').val();

        // Loop through the article list
        $(".articles li").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).find("span.date").text().search(new RegExp(filter_date, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

and I had to concatenate them like that in the **filter_date** variable as I couldn't figure out how to search for both Month AND Year when I change either one, as otherwise I'd get results filtered by either one of the two, but not both.

Now, my question is how can I combine the two blocks of code above into a single one or have them work together so that if I type something into the #filter input field AND select one (or both) options from Month / Year dropdowns, how could I get all three of those filters to work in unison to search for articles posted on specific year/month AS WELL AS containing certain text? Because right now it's either/or, not both.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need regex? I think you can achieve it using `indexOf`  like `$(this).find("span.date").text().indexOf(filter_date) > -1`

Comment: You may use something like `new RegExp("^" + filter_date + ".*" + filter.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') , "i")`.  The `^` stands for the start of string since the `Month Year` substring appears at the beginning of the searched text, right?

Comment: Month/Year substring appears at the beginning, yes, wrapped into its own <span class="date">...</span> tags

Comment: So, does this approach work?

Comment: Yes, that kinda worked. I just had to remove the ^ at the beginning of it, as sometimes the date selected won't be full Month & Year, but only Year, or only Month, so the string in the beginning of it all won't look like "Month Year" every time... thank you.